# Is it possible to do non-blocking Facebook API calls, using node.js?

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I want to use node.js to boost my Facebook applications performance. Imagine application that tries to compute who is you best friend on Facebook, fetching a lot of data from API calls - determining how many times your friends have posted to your wall, how many photos you have marked on together - so on.

So instead of running that calls one after one, as I do using PHP I have an idea to send them all together to Facebook using non-blocking, asynchronous nature of Node.js.

So overall execution time will be the time of most time consuming API call, but not the sum of execution time of the every call, right?

I try to use node-facebook-sdk (https://github.com/tenorviol/node-facebook-sdk) to make Facebook API calls and it seems to be that it's blocking, isn't it?

Just quick and dirty modification of example code, requesting 3 user profiles, seems that calls are not asynchronous, each sending to Facebook after previous has completed. Are there any way to avoid that?

Thank in advance!

```
var fbsdk = require('facebook-sdk');

var facebook = new fbsdk.Facebook({
  appId  : '_APPID_',
  secret : '_SECRET_'
});

var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  i++;
  console.log("TICK " + i);
}, 500);

facebook.api('/100000997949108', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

facebook.api('/1609464095', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

facebook.api('/100000560820400', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Looking at the fbsdk source that really should be asynchronous as it uses `http.request` underneath. You may have an issue with facebook not allowing you to multiple things in parallel due to some kind of locking mechanism.

Comment: Have you seen this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/, I think it's an alternative.

Comment: To get better performance I'm always trying to do as much of the facebook requests as possible in the client browser's and then sending the results to the server if necessary...

Comment: hey, Raynos, I've tried to send http get requests to Facebook http://graph.facebook.com, but w/o authorization and adding access_token - and it runs asynchronous.

Fbsdk works in synchronous way, I've addressed my question the the author already, will check your suggestions though obtaining access_token by raw http requests. May be Facebook blocks authenticated requests?

Comment: hey, Danny, I know about batching requests and already use them, but searching way to speed up my application more.
And I need unblocking library for Facebook to follow Node.js paradigm ;)

Comment: Raynos, thanks for pointing me, I've just checked fbsdk and it claims to use `CURL` to make requests, can it be issue?

Comment: may create an array of http servers that each do a single call for each user.  When done output results?

Comment: Looks like it runs async to me. The `facebook-sdk` module [uses `http[s].request`](https://github.com/tenorviol/node-facebook-sdk/blob/master/lib/facebook.js#L519), which is async. Also when I run your code everything looks like it runs asynchronously to me- the output even comes back in a different order than the requests are made. What does your output look like?

Answer (score 0):

This library will help you out with all things async. I hashed the particular method you would want to use for your problem, but the library as a whole is excellent at abstracting some of the more tedious (and ugly!) async patterns away. Great transitioning tool for those coming from procedural and you can take a peak under the covers if you want to learn some async patterns.

https://github.com/caolan/async/#parallel